# Mobile App development with Marmalade (C++)

Tags: android, c++, marmalade

I am interested in developing a mobile application, most likely for Android. The thing is, I have quite a bit of experience with C++, but none in Java or Objective-C. I'm looking into using the Marmalade SDK to help my develop apps in C++. My question is, how far can you get with Marmalade? Can an app be published to the Google Play store after only using Marmalade, or will I have to use something like Eclipse (and therefore Java) to make it a usable Android app? I'd like to use as much C++ as possible. Is that what Marmalade does, allow you to write an app start to finish in C++? The many other posts ive looked at haven't been too helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You better write them in their native programming language. It's worth learning the languages and create them seperately. `Objective-C` is just `C` with some extra classes and a weird coding structure and it is possible to mix it up with your `C++` code. Java is like the easiest programming languages to learn so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can an app be published to the Google Play store after only using
>   Marmalade, or will I have to use something like Eclipse (and therefore
>   Java) to make it a usable Android app?

You'll need to go through a few steps setting up the google play developer account (and etc) , and some of the packaging/submission tools require a Java installation, but basically you don't need anything else. The Marmalade SDK is quite friendly about guiding you through all the external steps you need to complete, with a useful dependency checker tool that tells you the links to go to and the things to install.

> Is that what Marmalade does, allow you to write an app start to finish in C++?

Yup.

> My question is, how far can you get with Marmalade?

I discovered Marmalade a few weeks back and had similar requirements to yours. Obviously there is a bit of a learning curve with any new piece of middleware, but I've been thoroughly happy with it so far.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Houssni's comment. Marmalade is basically just for games, acc. to my experience. If you try to create non-gaming apps with it, you'll get into so many troubles. The first one would be that you won't be able to access many of the Native capabilities directly in Marmalade's C++ code. FOr that you'll have to write your own extension/plugin using Marmalade's EDK which has to be coded in Java/Objective C. So in the end you'll have to use Java. Using Java only won't be enough for EDK, you'll need to access Java methods using JNI calls into C++. You can imagine the trouble you'll be having.

You can in theory write an app completely in C++, but practically it's not possible, unless you are making a game and doesn't need any native function (ads,push notifications, third party SDKs etc.). Apart from the native functions, creating UI in Marmalade is a pain and Marmalade stopped support for UI creator years ago. It's Native UI api doesn't work properly.

So in the end if it's a game, go for marmalade, if it doesn't you know what to do. The other alternative is Android NDK which allow writing apps in C++ using JNI.

Now to answer your other questions, you'd still need Android SDK to make APKs in Marmalade and Android NDK to compile EDK extensions.

Comment: I am using Marmalade IwNUI for a simple app and would really like to know what bugs you are referring to with the native UI support.

Comment: This answer was written almost a year ago, so I didn't remember the exact bugs and don't know if they have improved it yet. I stopped using IwNUI months ago. You can check the bug list on the answers site of marmalade. If you need native UI experience, I prefer Native App or Xamarin, instead of Marmalade.